# Inner products on super vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, traces, inner-product, super-linear-algebra

Let $V=V^0\oplus V^1$  be a super vector space (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_vector_space)

- Is there a special definition of an inner product on $V$ other than just an inner product on the underlying vector space (forgetting the grading)?
- Does the supertrace have a role in the induced inner product on the space $End(V)$ just like the trace has a role in the non graded case?

Comment: I would be interested in a reference answering this question!

Answer (score 4):

I am missing well written references for this (sign) sensitive topic! But here is what I learned from a few talks I have attended:

An inner product on the super vector space $V = V^0 \oplus V^1$ should be a *morphism* $B:V\otimes V \to \mathbb{K}$ of super vector spaces. The standard convention is to have $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{K}^{1|0}$ to be purely even. (But I have seen people use $\mathbb{K}^{0|1}$ or $\mathbb{K}^{1|1}$ instead.)

Then additionally one can require $B$ to be an even morphism, meaning that it vanishes on odd elements of $V\otimes V$, implying that homogenous vectors of opposite parity are orthogonal to each other.

Now $B$ is called symmetric if $B \circ c = B$ where $c:V\otimes V \overset{\sim}{\to} V\otimes V$ is the braiding which on homogenous elements $v,w$ is given by $v\otimes w \mapsto (-1)^{|v||w|}w\otimes v$.

(edited:)
Assume now $V$ is finite dimensional. Then $\mathrm{str}:\mathrm{End}(V) \to \mathbb{K}$ can be defined to be the unique linear map vanishing on superommutators with normalisation $\mathrm{str}(\mathrm{id}) = \mathrm{sdim} V = \dim V^0 - \dim V^1$.

Then \begin{align*}
\mathrm{End}(V)\otimes \mathrm{End}(V) &\to \mathbb{K}\\ A\otimes B &\mapsto \mathrm{str}(AB) \end{align*} defines an even, symmetric, non-degenerate bilinear form.

Comment: Perhaps I am confused. Doesn't your symmetry condition mean that the restriction of B to the odd part of V is a (non-super) anti-symmetric form? So a symplectic form if non-degenerate. Then it would not have the basis you claim, but a different one.

Comment: No, you are right it should be a (non-super) symplectic basis of $V^1$. I will edit the answer, thanks.

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries I removed the choice of basis and the presentation of the trace in coordinates. I believe one should actually use a 'difference' of two scalar products on $V^0$ and $V^1$ to do this (then negative definite on $V^1$), but this seems arbitrary to me.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answer, a very good reference on that matter is the [book of Yuri Ivanovich Manin "Gauge Field Theory and Complex Geometry"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-07386-5), specifically Chapter 3 "Introduction to superalgebra", even more specifically Section 5 "Scalar products" of that chapter.